# BorderLayout in Swing Java not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I have created a password generator in Java which works perfectly. My functionality is working (after a lot of tears, sweat and blood :) ), but the only problem that remains is the layout of my GUI.

My approach was the following:

- 1 pane (Top/North) for the title
- 1 pane in the center for the form
- 1 pane (bottom/south) for the buttons and textfield

This is the result

[image]

as you can see this is not how I wanted it. But if I look at my code, it should be placed nicely from top to bottom.

Where did it go wrong?

My code:

The **constructor** (extends from JFrame)

```
public PasswordGenerator(){
    this.setContentPane(ContentPane());
    this.setSize(500,270);
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

The panes:

```
private JPanel ContentPane()
{
    JPanel ContentPane = new JPanel();
    ContentPane.add(getTopPane(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    ContentPane.add(getCenterPane(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    ContentPane.add(getSouthPane(),BorderLayout.EAST);
    return ContentPane;
}

private JPanel getTopPane(){
    JPanel TopPane = new JPanel();
    JLabel intro = new JLabel("Password generator V1.0");
    intro.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.BOLD,20));
    TopPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    TopPane.add(intro);
    return TopPane;
}

private JPanel getCenterPane(){
    JPanel CenterPane = new JPanel();

    CenterPane.add(aantalChars);
    CenterPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,3));
    //8,2
    hidden.setVisible(false);
    hiddenL.setVisible(false);
    CenterPane.add(aantalCharsLabel);
    CenterPane.add(hidden);
    CenterPane.add(hidden);
    CenterPane.add(hiddenL);
    CenterPane.add(lowerCase);
    CenterPane.add(lowerCaseLabel);
    CenterPane.add(upperCase);
    CenterPane.add(upperCaseLabel);
    CenterPane.add(numberCase);
    CenterPane.add(numberCaseLabel);
    CenterPane.add(symbolCase);
    CenterPane.add(symbolCaseLabel);


    return CenterPane;
}
```

Comment: JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default, take a closer look at your ContentPane method

Comment: I tried the method ContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout()) but it gives an even crazier look of the GUI.

Comment: Did you set it before or after you added the components to it? You will need to set it before adding any components to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to set the `BorderLayout` as `LayoutManager` on your `ContentPane`. Just using the right constraints is not enough. You can use `ContentPane.setLayoutManager()` for this, or you can give the `LayoutManager` directly in the constructor of `JPanel`.

Comment: What constraints are to use in the ContentPane.setLayout() then? I tried just (new BorderLayout()) but it gives a very psychedelic view of the GUI.

Comment: `new BorderLayout()` is fine. What do you mean by psychedelic view?

Comment: Ah, maybe psychedelic means you have used `EAST` where you wanted `SOUTH` for your button bar?

Comment: Thanks for that notice. It works now but I am very dissapointed by the result. It sadly doesn't handle the whitespaces around the items well. I guess I'll have to do some more researching about these layout managers. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html In the meantime you could accept my answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The default layout manager for JPanel is FlowLayout manager.
To use BorederLayout you need to set it specifically :

```
private JPanel ContentPane()
        {
            JPanel ContentPane = new JPanel();
            //////////////////////////////////////////////
            ContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            ////////////////////////////////////////////
            ContentPane.add(getTopPane(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            ContentPane.add(getCenterPane(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
            ContentPane.add(getSouthPane(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            return ContentPane;
        }
```